# Google Drive REST API Documentation working directory

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) instructions of QuickStart Google Drive REST API in PHP but in the part where say "working directory" I need to move the quickstart.php and client_secret.json but I don't know where is the working directory.

I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 with Apache and PHP 5.6 and only I need to put these files in that working directory, not working in htdocs in Apache folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working directory can be any web accessible directory in `htdocs` folder, for example `my_google_disk`. But don't forget to restrict access to the `client_secret.json` file. You can do it in 3 ways:

1) The most simple will be to save `client_secret.json` contents in PHP string variable inside your script, for example:

```
$clientSecretData = '{...}' // client_secret.json data here
```

Then you just need to decode the contents of the variable to get JSON string as array as follows:

```
 $clientSecretData = json_decode($clientSecretData, true);
```

2) You can save it in any web accessible directory (`htdocs/my_google_disk`, for example), but then you need to create `.htaccess` file in that directory and save there special directives for access control:

```
<Files "client_secret.json">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

After that, try to access this file by URL `http://example.com/my_google_disk/client_secret.json` (`example.com` = your domain name) and you'll see a 404 Forbidden error.

You'll be able to get data from that file in `htdocs/my_google_disk/quickstart.php` as follows:

```
$clientSecretData = file_get_contents('client_secret.json');
```

3) Save it inside directory, that is located a level higher than the `htdocs` directory, for example, `C:\apache\private_files`. `private_files` here must be not accessible by URL. Set this directory to [include path](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php#refsect1-function.set-include-path-examples) in your script. Then you'll be able to get data from that file in your script from `htdocs/my_google_disk` directory as follows:

```
$clientSecretData = file_get_contents('../../private_files/client_secret.json');
```

Comment: Perfect! Working directory is htdocs. Was missing Google Api composer located in C:/Windows/SysWOW64/vendor/autoload.php and replacing the second line to require_once 'C:/Windows/SysWOW64/vendor/autoload.php'; the script works like a charm.